# Sending and receiving data in batches in sockets

Tags: c, sockets, ipc, unix-socket

So, I was trying out an UNIX domain client/server program and trying to send data over in batches. Let's say the server wants to send 1000 bytes of data in 10 batches of 100 bytes. Can we do it?
Parts of my program where I send data

**Server.c**

```
// assume str is a string with names of animals separated by "\t"
ret = write(msgSocket, str, strlen(str));
if(ret==-1){ 
    perror("error while sending data to client");
}
```

**Client.c**

```
memset(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
ret = read(msgSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
if(ret==-1){
    perror("error while receiving data");
}
```

In this part the whole data gets transferred at once, how can we do it in batches? Specifically the `str` is a large string in which names of let's say 100 animals are stored separated by `"\t"`. How can we send names of 10 animals at a time?

Comment: Only tag the language you are actually using. (Removed [tag:C++]. Replace [tag:C] with [tag:C++] if that is the correct language.)

Comment: Recommendation: Show [mre]s, not snippets. Snippets almost always lack context that you didn't know you needed to provide..

Comment: Are you using byte stream? If so, data is sent byte-by-byte and it doesn't matter what size chunks you read. You need to do framing yourself, if you need datagrams.

Comment: Unix domain sockets are streaming sockets, so you are creating a single sequence of bytes, and you are reading a single sequence of bytes. If you want to read 10 block of 100 bytes, you will to repeatedly read blocks of 100 bytes, which is done by repeatedly reading bytes until you have 100.

Comment: Crucially, neither `write` nor `read` is guaranteed to write/read the number of bytes you pass to them. You need to call them in loop. Both of your snippets are buggy.

Comment: To gain understanding of what you need to do, you can first write a version which reads one byte at  a time, and combines them after reading. Then write a more efficient, but also more complex, version which has larger buffer.

Comment: Side note: `memset(buffer,0,BUFFER_SIZE);` is usually a waste of time. `read` will write over 0 or more of the zeroes and return the number of bytes read, so you know exactly where to stop. If you need to null-terminate, you can drop the null at `buffer[ret]` and write only one zero instead of `BUFFER_SIZE` zeroes. Note that to successfully null terminate, you need to make sure you left enough space for the null terminator, and it's not clear if you've done this.

Comment: Step 1: count how many bytes is 10 animals. Step 2: send that many bytes

Comment: A TCP connection is a stream of bytes. There are no messages. The reader does not know and cannot know how many bytes were sent in each individual invocation of `send()`. If you want messages, you need to implement them yourself by e.g. explicitly sending message length before the message itself.